# Git: Show all branches that touch a certain file

Tags: git, branch

How can I obtain a list of all branches that introduce changes to a certain file?

Context: When starting to edit a certain file it might be interesting to see what unmerged changes exist on the same file.

We can assume that all branches that are already merged are also deleted. However, if we can filter on branches that are ahead of [main] it would be a plus.

Comment: This problem is a bit underspecified. Suppose for instance that you're on your `main` and you also have a branch `br1` that is two commits ahead. The first of these commits changes some files, and the second one changes them all back. Is `br1`, which is 2 ahead of `main` and has changes to files, of interest, because one of its commits changes those files? Or is it not of interest, because the *second* of those commits changes them *back?*

Comment: If you only want to look at the *tip commits* of the other branches (other branch names), it's easy: just iterate over all the names and examine each tip commit (count its ahead and/or behind numbers as well) and compare the snapshot in *that* tip commit to the snapshot in the `main` tip commit. You'll find recipes for the ahead/behind counts, and for the comparing, in numerous existing SO questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a pure git way to do it. However, you can achieve this by a Bash one-liner:

```
$ git branch --no-merged | xargs -I branch bash -c "git diff --stat master...branch | grep -q rails/apps/main/Gemfile.lock && echo branch"
```

`git branch -a --no-merged` will give you all unmerged branches; local and remote (`-a`)
Pipe that to xargs to run the following command for every line of output and replace `branch` by the actual branch name (`-I branch`):
`bash -c "..."` runs the quoted argument in a new Bash so we can use `|` and `&&` on the output of the next command instead of the output of xargs.
`git diff --stat master...branch` lists all files changed by that branch.
Pipe that to `grep -q path/to/Gemfile.lock` which will either exit with success or failed (`-q`).
On success (`&&`) echo the branch name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a bash function, which you can optionally make into a Git alias.

```bash
function git_where_changed {
    for commit in $(git rev-list --all -- $1); do
        if ! git merge-base --is-ancestor $commit main; then
            git branch -a --contains $commit
        fi
    done | sort -u | sed -E 's/^ +//'; 
}
```

After re-loading your `.bashrc`, you would run this as `git_where_changed path/to/file`.

`git rev-list --all` lists every commit that is part of any branch or tag. The `-- $1` limits the results to commits that changed the file that matches the first argument to the function (`path/to/file`).

`git merge-base --is-ancestor $commit main` checks whether the first commit (`$commit`, taken from the `rev-list` output) is an ancestor to the second commit (the head of the `main` branch). If so, that commit is already merged and we can ignore it.

`git branch -a --contains $commit` produces a list of branches that `$commit` is part of. `-a` includes tracked remote branches; without this, only local branches will be included.

At the end of the `for` loop, there may be a lot of duplicate branch names, for instance if there is one unmerged branch that changed the file several times. `sort -u` sorts the branch names alphabetically and removes the duplicates. Finally, `sed -E 's/^ +//'` removes the whitespace that `git branch` normally places in front of its output (`-E` enables extended regular expression syntax).

As an alias, it would look like this (under the `[alias]` heading in your `.gitconfig`):

```ini
where-changed = "!f() { for commit in $(git rev-list --all -- $1); do if ! git merge-base --is-ancestor $commit main; then git branch -a --contains $commit; fi; done | sort -u | sed -E 's/^ +//'; };f"
```

This would allow you to run `git where-changed path/to/file`, which may be more convenient if you are using Git on Windows and not using Git Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Update all remote tracking branches,

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

List all remote tracking branches,

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin --format='%(refname:short)'
```

Check each remote tracking branch if it has some new commits, not reachable from `main`, that touch a certain file `foo.bar`. If any, print the branch name and commits. Combined with `git for-each-ref`,

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin --format='%(refname:short)' | while read ref;do
    commits=$(git log --pretty=%H main..${ref} --follow -- foo.bar)
    if [[ "$commits" != "" ]];then
        echo $ref $commits
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified revision of the @AmShaegar's answer:

```
for branch in $(git branch --format='%(refname:short)' --no-merged master); do
  git diff --quiet master...$branch -- <your-path> || echo $branch
done
```

*Explanation:*

First, we get the unmerged branch names. The `--format='%(refname:short)'` prevents printing the '*' for the current branch. Then, we test every branch if it has differences against the master using the `git diff` only. The `--quiet` makes it silent and implies `--exit-code` which in turn makes the program exit with codes similar to diff. So we can use it without piping to `grep`.